# Docker database data saving

Tags: docker

Lets say I have a PHP+MySQL application built on Docker and it runs on my server.
Many people register accounts, many things are saving to database.

As I understand Docker is a process that after restart doesn't have the previous data, I can just build a container based on a given image over again in case I restart machine or do something wrong.

What is the reason of using it on production environment then? 
A single restart of a server could ruin all the data that was there.

Does it save anyhow? Do I understand it wrong?

Comment: Docker uses Volumes for persistence and your data is never lost. You have to define volumes when building images or inside docker-compose.

Comment: @thenrun Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I understand it wrong?

Most likely yes.

Persistence in docker is supported via [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) or [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I must have missed it while reading the documentation.